# Текстовый редактор на PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, текст

Есть такая программа, как **WordPad**. В нем, как и в любом текстовом редакторе, есть функция изменения "свойств" текста, выделенного мышкой.То есть изменяется лишь часть текста, а если текст не выделен, то дальше вводимый текст будет иметь такие "свойства".

[image]
*Панель изменения текста*
[image]
*Выделенный жирный и курсивный текст.*

Как реализовать это на **PyQt5**, используя **QPlainTextEdit**?

Comment: Предположительно никак. Для этого нужен `QTextEdit`. Когда делал такой редактор, то использовал QTextEdit: https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Взял старый код](https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager/blob/master/FormattingToolbar/FormattingToolbar.cpp#L152) редактора и сделал небольшой пример, который покажет как делать форматирование кода.

Аналогично через `merge_format_on_word_or_selection` можно сделать и другие штуки: изменение шрифта, подчеркивание, зачеркивание, изменение цвета и т.п.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.sb_font_size = Qt.QSpinBox()
        self.sb_font_size.setRange(5, 40)
        self.sb_font_size.valueChanged.connect(self._on_font_size_changed)

        self.text_edit = Qt.QTextEdit('Test this!')

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.sb_font_size)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        central_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def _on_font_size_changed(self, value):
        text_char_format = Qt.QTextCharFormat()
        text_char_format.setFontPointSize(value)

        self.merge_format_on_word_or_selection(text_char_format)

    def merge_format_on_word_or_selection(self, text_char_format):
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        if not cursor.hasSelection():
            cursor.select(Qt.QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)

        cursor.mergeCharFormat(text_char_format)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]